# How can I fetch data from a REST API where field names vary and how to type it in typescript?

Tags: typescript, api, rest

I've had trouble fetching an API because an object field name can vary from one object to another, as well as the number of children of this same object:

```
[
  {
    "name": {
      "common": "Finland",
      "official": "Republic of Finland",
      "nativeName": {
        "fin": {
          "official": "Suomen tasavalta",
          "common": "Suomi"
        },
        "swe": {
          "official": "Republiken Finland",
          "common": "Finland"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "name": {
      "common": "Guatemala",
      "official": "Republic of Guatemala",
      "nativeName": {
        "spa": {
          "official": "República de Guatemala",
          "common": "Guatemala"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Here `nativeName`'s first child can be `spa` or `fin` depending on the object, and there can be one or two (and even more in other instances) children.

How can I get to the first `nativeName`'s `common` value here ?

Also, how can I type this data in typescript ? So far, I left it as such :

```
type name = {
  name: {
    common: string,
    official: string,
    nativeName: {
      var1: {
        official: string,
        common: string
      },
      var2: {
        official: string,
        common: string
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
I realize I have one last question:

```
"languages": {
      "spa": "Spanish"
    }
```

here `spa` varies as well as the number of entries in `languages`, how would I type that in typescript?

Comment: If it's 2 different objects you csn type it as `Object1 | Object2` - `Object1` or `Object2`.
You'll have to implement custom logic to decide between the 2 when your API call finishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first question:

```
const nameObj =  {
    "name": {
      "common": "Finland",
      "official": "Republic of Finland",
      "nativeName": {
        "fin": {
          "official": "Suomen tasavalta",
          "common": "Suomi"
        },
        "swe": {
          "official": "Republiken Finland",
          "common": "Finland"
        }
      }
    }
  }

const firstCommon = Object.values(nameObj.name.nativeName)[0].common
```

second question:

```
type name = {
  name: {
    common: string,
    official: string,
    nativeName: {
      [key: string]: {
        official: string,
        common: string
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: cheers ! I realize I have one last question (I'll edit the main post for more visibility).     ```"languages": {
      "spa": "Spanish"
    }``` here `spa` varies as well as the number of entries in `languages`, how would I type that ?

Comment: languages: { [key: string]: string }

Comment: you're welcome. 
good lock